# Twilio Worker: Uncaught TypeError: this._setupWebsocket is not a function

Tags: angular, twilio

I'm busy with Twilio Taskrouter in Angular 2 but I'm getting an error whenever I execute:
`Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(tokenData._workerToken);`

The error I'm getting is `Uncaught TypeError: this._setupWebsocket is not a function`

These are the functions my injectable executes:

```
  this.getTokens("Bob","http://contactcenter.brancheteers.nl/api/twilio/twilioToken","TwilioToken");
  this.getTokens("workerSId here","http://contactcenter.    brancheteers.nl/api/taskrouter/workerToken","WorkerToken");

  getTokens(inputData, url, tokenType) {
    var getData;
    var x = this.http.get(url + "/" + inputData).map(response => response.json());
    x.subscribe(
      data => getData = data,
      error => console.error("HTTP REQUEST FAILED getTokens@baMsgCenter"),
      () => this.initToken(tokenType, getData)
    );
  }

  initToken(tokenType, tokenData) {
    if(tokenType == "WorkerToken") { Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(tokenData._workerToken);  }
    if(tokenType == "TwilioToken") { Twilio.Device.setup(tokenData._token);  }
  }
```

I also added 
`declare const Twilio: any;` above the `@injectable()`

and to debug I logged to see if a valid worker token is being returned, and that works fine. Also worth noting that the twilio device does work. And whenever I delete the line `twilio.taskrouter ...` the error is gone

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it's a bug. To clarify what I want, I want the error to dissepear and for the Twilio.Taskrouter.Worker to work so that I can dequeue calls to the worker.

```
    at Function.Worker (http://media.twiliocdn.com/taskrouter/js/v1.0/taskrouter.worker.min.js:1:3135)
    at BaMsgCenterService.initToken (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:2682:31)
    at SafeSubscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:2678:181)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:589:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:574:26)
    at Subscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:498:26)
    at Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:480:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:498:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:480:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:61704:38)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4262:35)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:30261:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4261:40)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4138:47)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4332:33)
  -------------   Elapsed: 1246 ms; At: Tue Feb 28 2017 14:26:34 GMT+0100 (CET)   -------------  
    at getStacktraceWithUncaughtError (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:3857:12) [angular]
    at new LongStackTrace (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:3851:22) [angular]
    at Object.onScheduleTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:3907:18) [angular]
    at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4239:49) [angular]
    at Zone.scheduleEventTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4158:39) [angular]
    at zoneAwareAddListener (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:5213:14) [angular]
    at XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener (eval at createNamedFn (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:5319:17), <anonymous>:3:43) [angular]
    at Observable._subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:61749:18) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:119:27) [angular]
    at MapOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12258:23) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:116:22) [angular]
    at BaMsgCenterService.getTokens (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:2678:11) [angular]
    at new BaMsgCenterService (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:2629:14) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_BaPageTop0.createInternal (/NgaModule/BaPageTop/component.ngfactory.js:131:35) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.create (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:79954:21) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.create (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:80406:44) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_Pages0.createInternal (/PagesModule/Pages/component.ngfactory.js:73:19) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.create (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:79954:21) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.create (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:80406:44) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_Pages_Host0.createInternal (/PagesModule/Pages/host.ngfactory.js:16:19) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:79967:21) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.createHostView (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:80423:52) [angular]
    at ComponentFactory.create (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:42290:25) [angular]
    at ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:59196:62) [angular]
    at RouterOutlet.activate (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:65027:40) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:23870:16) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:23837:26) [angular]
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:23773:58 [angular]
    at Array.forEach (native) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:23773:29) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:23747:14) [angular]
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:23315:22 [angular]
    at SafeSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:157:25) [angular]
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:589:16) [angular]
    at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:538:22) [angular]
    at Subscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:491:26) [angular]
    at Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12287:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15738:30) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:85755:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12287:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at ReduceSubscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:33891:30) [angular]
    at ReduceSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:480:18) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15730:30) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:480:18) [angular]
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:8633:24) [angular]
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:119:27) [angular]
    at MergeMapOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15680:23) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:116:22) [angular]
    at ReduceOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:33850:23) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:116:22) [angular]
    at MapOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12258:23) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:116:22) [angular]
    at Object.subscribeToResult (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:679:27) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15725:38) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15722:14) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15705:18) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15738:30) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:85755:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12287:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at EverySubscriber.notifyComplete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47338:26) [angular]
    at EverySubscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47355:14) [angular]
    at EverySubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:480:18) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15730:30) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:480:18) [angular]
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:8633:24) [angular]
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:119:27) [angular]
    at MergeMapOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15680:23) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:116:22) [angular]
    at EveryOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47318:23) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:116:22) [angular]
    at MapOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12258:23) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:116:22) [angular]
    at Object.subscribeToResult (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:679:27) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15725:38) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15722:14) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15705:18) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12287:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15738:30) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:85755:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12287:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at ScalarObservable._subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:46766:24) [angular]
    at ScalarObservable.Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:119:27) [angular]
    at MapOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12258:23) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:116:22) [angular]
    at Object.subscribeToResult (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:679:27) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15725:38) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15722:14) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15705:18) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:491:26) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12287:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12287:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12287:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at LastSubscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:66978:25) [angular]
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:480:18) [angular]
    at MergeAllSubscriber.notifyComplete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15583:30) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:85762:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:480:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:498:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:480:18) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:498:26) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:480:18) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber._emitFinal (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47600:25) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber._emit (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47582:14) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber._tryPredicate (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47574:18) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47558:18) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MergeAllSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:640:26) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:85755:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:491:26) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15738:30) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:85755:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12287:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:491:26) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber._emitFinal (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47599:25) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber._emit (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47582:14) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber._tryPredicate (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47574:18) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47558:18) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MergeAllSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:640:26) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:85755:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:491:26) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15738:30) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:85755:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12287:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:491:26) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber._emitFinal (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47599:25) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber._emit (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47582:14) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber._tryPredicate (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47574:18) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:47558:18) [angular]
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MergeAllSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:640:26) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:85755:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:491:26) [angular]
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15738:30) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:85755:21) [angular]
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at Object.subscribeToResult (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:674:25) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15725:38) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15722:14) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15705:18) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at ScalarObservable._subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:46766:24) [angular]
    at ScalarObservable.Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:119:27) [angular]
    at MergeMapOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15680:23) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:116:22) [angular]
    at CatchOperator.call (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:46812:23) [angular]
    at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:116:22) [angular]
    at Object.subscribeToResult (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:679:27) [angular]
    at MergeAllSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:15563:42) [angular]
    at MergeAllSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:455:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:12287:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (
```

Comment: How did this project work out ? Just wanting some insight into how simple/complexity it was to use typescript with taskrouter JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(tokenData._workerToken);`

is an object so you'll need to specify `new` i.e.

`new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(tokenData._workerToken);`

It's not clear how you're using the `Worker` but you may want to consider assigning it to a variable, so you can call its methods later.

`var worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(tokenData._workerToken);`

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem! I wasn't using the worker at all, just calling the object.

Comment: Do you know of any good examples of angular2 and up apps that showcase how to use typescript in angular with references and interactions with taskrouter reservations?